# Bukkit ProtocolLib Nametags

Tags: java, bukkit

I am trying to change the name above a players entity. I have successfully done this but it has a side effect of changeing the players skin to the default. How can I change the player's nametag without resetting their skin.

Plugin Librarys Used

- ProtocolLib
- PacketWrapper

Code used to change name

```
public void changeNameOnHead(Player player, String name) {
 PlayerInfoData pid = new
 PlayerInfoData(WrappedGameProfile.fromPlayer(player), 1,
  EnumWrappers.NativeGameMode.SURVIVAL,
  WrappedChatComponent.fromText(player.getName()));


 WrapperPlayServerPlayerInfo wpspi = new WrapperPlayServerPlayerInfo();
 wpspi.setAction(EnumWrappers.PlayerInfoAction.REMOVE_PLAYER);
 wpspi.setData(Collections.singletonList(pid));


 for (Player p: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
  if (p.equals(player)) {
   continue;
  }
  p.hidePlayer(player);
  wpspi.sendPacket(p);
 }

 ProtocolLibrary.getProtocolManager().addPacketListener(
  new PacketAdapter(RoleplayEngine.Instance,
   PacketType.Play.Server.PLAYER_INFO) {

   @Override
   public void onPacketSending(PacketEvent event) {

    if (event.getPacket().getPlayerInfoAction().read(0) != EnumWrappers.PlayerInfoAction.ADD_PLAYER) {
     return;
    }

    PlayerInfoData pid =
     event.getPacket().getPlayerInfoDataLists().read(0).get(0);

    if (pid.getProfile().getUUID() !=
     player.getUniqueId()) return;


    PlayerInfoData newPid = new PlayerInfoData(
     pid.getProfile().withName(name),
     pid.getPing(),
     pid.getGameMode(),
     WrappedChatComponent.fromText(name)
    );


    event.getPacket().getPlayerInfoDataLists().write(0,
     Collections.singletonList(newPid));

   }
  }
 );

 for (Player p: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
  if (p.equals(player)) {
   continue;
  }
  p.showPlayer(player);
 }

}
```

Comment: Relevant https://bukkit.org/threads/edit-name-tag-above-players-without-other-plugins-or-loss-of-skin.172300/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [this library](https://gist.github.com/aadnk/0502e32369f203daaba9) available in github to change the player's name and skin.

Quick example of usage:

```
PlayerDisplayModifier p = new PublicDisplayModifier(plugin);
p.changeDisplay(myPlayer, "SkinPlayer", "NewName");
```

This works if your server is 1.8 and lower, not sure if it works on higher versions.

---

If your server version is higher than 1.8, you can try using [NickNamerIntegratedApi](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/nicknamer-integrated-api.5341/), a plugin that also has an API for devs. It's open sourced, so you can probably dig for the piece of code that makes the nick change possible

Lastly, you can also try to use [md-5's iTAG](https://github.com/md-5/iTag/), and a good [fork of it](https://github.com/ataranlen/iTag/issues/1) by ataranlen